# pandas: do not count nan in an aggregate function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate, aggregate-functions, nan

I have the following code:

```
data_agg_df = data_df.groupby("team", as_index=False).player.agg({"player_set": lambda x: set(list(x)), "player_count": "nunique"})
```

Then my results look like:

```
team           player_set         player_count
-------------------------------------------------
 A           {John, Mary}          2
 B           {nan}                 0
 C           {Dave,nan}            1
```

I am wondering how to not show the nana in the player_set? i.e. I want the resulting data frame look like:

```
team           player_set         player_count
-------------------------------------------------
 A           {John, Mary}          2
 B           {}                    0
 C           {Dave}                1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
set(list(x))
```

with

```
set(list(i for i in x if pd.notnull(i)))
```

to take out the `nan`s